# Award a Bounty to a Competing Answer on a Relatively Uninteresting Question

Tags: discussion, bounties

Here's the situation:

1. I attempt to answer generic
   question.
2. Another user answers the same question.  We comment back-and-forth and I get some very useful information out of that exchange, which happens to be very helpful and timely.
3. I don't want to let that go unrewarded.

So, as I understand I have two options:

1. Wait 2 days, offer a bounty on the question and wait 24 hours (With the unintended side-effect that the relatively uninteresting question will be featured).
2. Ask my own question, knowing more or less what the answer is already and award a bounty on it.

I'm not really sold on either option.  Opinions?

Comment: Seems to me that the usual response is to click on the other user's name, then on the profile go and look at some other answers and upvote them (should they deserve it, which they probably will because this is a helpful person.) They get rep, you learn still more from the user, everyone's happy.  (This seems usual to me because I occasionally see a pattern of three or four of my questions being upvoted in a short time span when they were answered a long way apart or are in different tags.) I have also done this myself, inspired by having it happen to me.

Comment: @Kate - this isn't recommended - if you vote for too many answers over a too short a time period you *will* trigger the vote fraud mechanisms and your votes will be rescinded.

Comment: @ChrisF - I am not talking 10+ votes, and not in 10-15 seconds either. It takes time to read over people's answers. Most people will not be patient enough to do more than 2 or 3. More than that and you're not upvoting because the answer is good, you're upvoting because of who wrote it, which I agree is wrong.

Comment: @Kate - that's OK, but someone else might not be as diligent as you.

Comment: @Kate / @ChrisF - The problem with that approach is if they've already hit the rep cap for the day (likely) it doesn't accomplish anything.  They'd only be interested in bounties/accepted answers at that point.

Comment: @kate I stole your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upvote his answer that turned out helpful?

Comment: That's easy enough but it doesn't really get someone who has already hit the rep cap for the day (or is likely to without your help) get any further ahead.

Answer (score 4):

I really like Kate's answer so I am stealing it.

> Seems to me that the usual response is to click on the other user's name, then on the profile go and look at some other answers and upvote them (should they deserve it, which they probably will because this is a helpful person.) They get rep, you learn still more from the user, everyone's happy. (This seems usual to me because I occasionally see a pattern of three or four of my questions being upvoted in a short time span when they were answered a long way apart or are in different tags.) I have also done this myself, inspired by having it happen to me.

Obviously you  want to go easy here, otherwise you'll trigger the vote anomaly detection:

- *read* the posts and take time to decide if they're worthy of your upvote
- remember answers are worth +10 and questions only +5
- don't do this for more than a few posts

Comment: Surely if the reasoning is a direct quote, you should at least make your post CW? Since, it is, after all, a community effort.

Comment: @waiwai, meh, Kate had more than enough time to repost as an answer. With that in mind, I see this as a valid "penalty" for using a comment to write an answer.

Comment: Clearly, anyone who thinks I should be awarded rep anyway knows a good way to do it now :-). Honoured to be stolen from, Jeff.